# Can you come up with a formula to generate this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

If $'n'$ belongs to the natural numbers, I need to find an equation $'u(n)'$ that corresponds to the following table:

[image: Sequence]

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Also, I'd appreciate it if anyone knows how to make the image show in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u(n)$ corresponds to the $n$th raw moment of a $N(1+\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable, with moment generating function $M(t)=\exp((1+\mu)t+\sigma^2t^2/2)$. From this we have $$u(n)=\left.\frac{{\rm d}^n}{{\rm d}t^n}\exp((1+\mu)t+\sigma^2t^2/2)\right|_{t=0}$$